# When tableview cell is selected twice it crashes with error found unexpected nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Essentially I have a table view controller with cells populated from JSON data. When the user selects the cell a different view controller should open with more information about the cell selected.

I am using user defaults to pass information about the cell selected and what is needed in the POST request to retrieve the data.

The issue is when a cell is selected I sometimes get the error, found unexpected nil.

This usually occurs when the cell is selected, the different view controller is presented, I go back to tableview and select the same cell.

I believe the issue has something to do with `dequeueReusableCell` because I have noticed reloading the tableview data in viewDidAppear with `fetchJSON` lowers the chance the error is found.

Without this change, the error would occur all the time.

```
import UIKit



class ScheduleCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellStructure: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testingCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickupLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var deliveryLabel: UILabel!

}

 class ScheduleTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UIBarButtonItem!
    var driverName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name")!
    var structure = [ScheduleStructure]()
    var pickupTitle = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        fetchJSON()
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl


    }

    private func fetchJSON() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://example/example/example.php"),
            let value = driverName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
            else { return }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "driverName=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }


            do {
                self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([ScheduleStructure].self,from:data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }

            }.resume()

    }






        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return structure.count
    }


        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customerID", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleCell



            cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.clear

            let portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
            //cell.textLabel?.text = portfolio.customer


            cell.pickupLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.pickupLabel.clipsToBounds = true

            return cell

        }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return self.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
    }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customerID", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleCell
            //cell.cellStructure.layer.cornerRadius = 50
            let portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]
            let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "deliveryController")


            pickupTitle = portfolio.customer
            UserDefaults.standard.set(pickupTitle, forKey: "TitleText")
            controller.navigationItem.title = pickupTitle
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

            self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 160.0
        }
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        fetchJSON()


        }


}
```

Comment: Put an exception breakpoint and check where it is getting crashed. Possiblities "structure" doesn't have data, portfolio.customer is nil, navigationController is nil

Comment: Maybe not related but delete the line `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell....` in `didSelectRowAt`.  You **must not** dequeue cells outside of `cellForRowAt` . You will never get the cell you expect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it could be because when you get back to the view the tableView takes time to reload it's data again, that's why you're getting nil.
try this inside fetchJSON()

```
 do {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([ScheduleStructure].self,from:data)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
```